# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el tipo de un input?

Tags: php, html

¿Es posible obtener el tipo de input de un formulario enviado a PHP

En HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="text01">
```

¿Cómo obtengo el valor de el atributo type en PHP?

como para verificar que el usuario no modificó el tipo de input, en PHP

Ejemplo

Código Real:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha" value="2019-06-01">
```

Codigo Modificado por el usuario:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha" value="texto diferente">
```

Comment: Javier, cuál es el propósito de validar que el input no fue cambiado en el front? En PHP al final, sea un date o un text en HTML, recibirás una cadena que podrás convertir en algún tipo de date si lo requieres...

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, el fin no es validarlo en el front, si no en el backend, ya que el usuario también podría modificar el verificador de Javascript, e inyectar valores no deseados en el formulario...

Comment: Así es, la validación de los datos del form debe de hacerse en el back. No creo que exista una forma sencilla o que (pienso yo) valga el esfuerzo validar código HTML en el back para lo que tu pregunta plantea específicamente. Te recomendaría simplemente validarlo intentando parsear el parámetro fecha a un date y regresar un error si no es así, pero no me parece buena idea tratar de averiguar si es un input date o un text.

Comment: Las comprobaciones son en el cliente, si quieres validar por si el usuario ha cambiado los valores, ten en una variable los valores originales y compáralos con lo que escriba el usuario.

Comment: para esto te sugiero realizar validaciones como dices backend tal como indica aca: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271381/correctly-determine-if-date-string-is-a-valid-date-in-that-format

Answer (score 0):

La función de php que te puede ayudar es gettype()

```
$var = "hola mundo";
echo gettype($var);
// salida : string
```

Comment: Saludos, esto solo te devolvera el tipo de la variable mas no el tipo de input desde el cual se envia la variable..!!

Comment: Toda la razón, comprendí mal lo que se necesitaba.